# Log a Dictionary in Serilog, where Value type is a class

Tags: c#, dictionary, serilog

I have a `Dictionary<string, object>` where the values are of different class types. When I try to log the dictionary, the content is not properly displayed.

```
_logger.LogInformation("Printing Dictionary: {@myDictionary}", myDictionary);
```

Results in

> Printing Dictionary: {"KEY1":{"$type" : "ClassNameOne"}, {"KEY2":{"$type" : "ClassNameTwo"}}

The desired result is `{"KEY1":{"ClassOnesFirstProperty" : "PropertyValue","ClassOnesSecondProperty" : "PropertyValue"}, {"KEY2":{"ClassTwosFirstProperty" : "PropertyValue"}}`

Or at least something that shows me the actual data. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Putting that sort of information in a log message defeats the point of structured logging, Use ForContext and log as a structured component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution: serialize the dictionary before logging it. So,

```
_logger.LogInformation("Printing Dictionary: {@myDictionary}", myDictionary);
```

Should become

```
_logger.LogInformation("Printing Dictionary: {@myDictionary}", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myDictionary));
```